# How to commit only a specific directory to a remote branch? (deleting all other content)

Tags: git, deployment, bitbucket, plesk, continuous-deployment

I have a branch named `deployment` and I want to push only the contents of the folder `dist` to this branch in my remote repository, deleting all other content.

**I have tried so far**

- Flag `git push` with `--prefix`
- `cd dist` and `git push`

**Observations**

1. A warning that says it is already up-to-date
2. Remote has everything in there (and not just the 'dist' folder)

**How do I select only `dist/` folder in my commit?**

Comment: I'm also very confused about what you are trying to do.  In Git, when you commit, you logically take a snapshot of your entire branch, and when you push, you logically push your entire branch.  Why are you trying to just push the contents of a single folder?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen as mentioned in my post, I'm trying to push the contents of the 'dist' folder which are my compiled files. The Plesk Git extension then connects to that branch and continously mirrors everything on my production server. It's basically continous deployment. I have been trying things for over 15 hours with no luck -- this is the strategy I'm trying out now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you want to

> Commit only a specific directory to a remote branch (deleting all other content)

Since `deployment` is created (branched out) from a branch that has all the files, you will need to delete unwanted files in the `deployment` branch. You can get to the desired state with the following steps:

1. Pull the latest changes: `git reset --hard HEAD; git fetch`
2. Go to your branch: `git checkout deployment`
3. Delete unwanted files/directories (other than *dist/*): `find * -maxdepth 0 -name 'dist' -prune -o -exec rm -rf '{}' ';'`
4. Stage deleted changes: `git add .`
5. Commit & push to remote: `git commit -m "Commit message"; git push origin  deployment`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks -- unfortunately got stuck right at step1. getting `PS C:\02 A14 WORK\01 SOFTWARE\AngularTemplate> git checkout deployment
error: pathspec 'deployment' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Comment: I have edited my answer to pull state of your remote repository to local. As mentioned, this will only download all the recent changes, but will not change your current working area.

Comment: thanks -- I just got some time this evening again to try things out. I've started to grasp the logic and what checkout does/how it works. Now my only problem is that git still pushes all of my files to that branch this way, not just the contents of 'dist'.

Comment: Now, the issue is that the contents of the 'dist' are already on the remote. Try creating a new branch and do the same. OR do you have to keep this branch only?

Comment: I'm using a test repository so I can try things out. I just made a new branch using git checkout -b deployment2 and then followed along, unfortunately everything keeps getting copied across

Comment: I am assuming the `branch` you branched out `deployment2` will have all the changes. So, delete the files you do not need in `deployment2` and push to remote. Need more explanation on this?

Comment: Ah, that makes sense but unfortunately it's not what I need. Was looking at a way to do it programatically so I can have it in the script. I'm trying to use this as part of continuous deployment logic so I can't manually delete all other files.

Comment: With the magic of code, we should not do anything manually. I have updated the answer for this scenario. Please mark accepted if this gets your job done :)